# How to remove all specified part of the string?

Tags: c#

I have a string from html page, how to remove below part effectively?

```
<figure class="media-landscape has-caption full-width lead">
        <span class="image-and-copyright-container">

            <img class="js-image-replace" alt="corby" src="http://url.com/jpg" width="820" height="617" data-highest-encountered-width="950">

             <span class="off-screen">Photo by</span>
             <span class="story-image-copyright">AFP</span>

        </span>

        <figcaption class="media-caption">
            <span class="off-screen">Image caption</span>
            <span class="media-caption__text">
                Text..................
            </span>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
```

Comment: Use a HTML parser and then edit the parsed document.

Comment: Use [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/)

Comment: @Max something like htmlNode.Remove?

Comment: Select the node and set [InnerHtml](http://html-agility-pack.net/inner-html) to <div></div> or something like that. You can also use Remove see [Manipulation](http://html-agility-pack.net/manipulation)